# Javascript: Refresh select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML

```
<select id="v-1" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="624">Video 1</option>
    <option value="625">Video 2</option>
    <option value="626">Video 3</option>
    <option value="627">Video 4</option>
    <option value="628">Video 5</option>
    <option value="629">Video 6</option>
    <option value="630">Video 7</option>
</select>
```

In my javascript file, i have a function that removes some of the options by adding style="display: none;" to the option tag. For example:

```
<select id="v-1" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="624" style="display: none;">Video 1</option>
    <option value="625" style="display: none;">Video 2</option>
    <option value="626">Video 3</option>
    <option value="627" style="display: none;">Video 4</option>
    <option value="628">Video 5</option>
    <option value="629">Video 6</option>
    <option value="630" style="display: none;">Video 7</option>
</select>
```

But when I call $('#v-1').val(), the result is 624. I wanted the result to be 626 or the first option that doesn't have the style, display: none.

Comment: setting the display style of options to none doesnt change the select's value

Comment: "*or the first option that doesn't have the style, display: none.*" Regardless of user selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#v-1 option").each(function()
{
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
        alert($(this).val());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Doesn't matter if using above code will help. Anyhow display : none won't hide the option items in Macintosh computer.

Instead I would suggest to remove the element from the select and include it on the fly when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could, probably, do:

```
jQuery("#v-1").find("option:visible:selected").val();
```

To get the value of the selected option (and visible).
If you just want to get the value of the first visible option, you could do:

```
jQuery("#v-1").find("option:visible:eq(0)").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#v-1 option").each(function()
{
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
        alert($(this).val());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
    $('option:not(:checked)).val()

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use `disable` instead of `style="display: none;"` in your `option`

**Html-**

```
<select id="v-1" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="624" disabled="disabled" >Video 1</option>
    <option value="625" disabled="disabled">Video 2</option>
    <option value="626">Video 3</option>
    <option value="627" disabled="disabled">Video 4</option>
    <option value="628">Video 5</option>
    <option value="629">Video 6</option>
    <option value="630" disabled="disabled">Video 7</option>
</select>
```

**script**-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("#v-1").val());
})
```

**output:** 626

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v52hb28u/